# XCode: Warnings for constraints in output window

Tags: xcode, constraints, warnings

After starting my app I get a bunch of warnings or error messages in the debug output window (s.below):

I checked all warnings in Xcode editors and changed them until the last warning was gone. I also clicked on „Reset to suggested constraints“.
So there are still some problems, but I don’t know how to solve them. Should I remove all constraints and restart created them manualy or by default again???

```
DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000084b00 H:[NSImageView:0x610000161380(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000850a0 H:[NSImageView:0x610000161380]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6100001e0300]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000085000 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x610000161380]   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001815f0, '|':NameCellID:0x6100001815f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000084e20 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e0300(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000850f0 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e0300]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001815f0, '|':NameCellID:0x6100001815f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000832a0 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001815f0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000084e20 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e0300(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.344 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000835c0 H:[NSImageView:0x618000162d00(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000082a30 H:[NSImageView:0x618000162d00]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6180001e0900]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000836b0 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x618000162d00]   (Names: NameCellID:0x6180001805b0, '|':NameCellID:0x6180001805b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000080f00 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e0900(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000082d50 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e0900]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x6180001805b0, '|':NameCellID:0x6180001805b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000083840 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x6180001805b0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000080f00 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e0900(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.356 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000084560 H:[NSImageView:0x618000163c00(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000846a0 H:[NSImageView:0x618000163c00]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6180001e1200]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000084600 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x618000163c00]   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180750, '|':NameCellID:0x618000180750 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000845b0 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e1200(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000846f0 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e1200]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180750, '|':NameCellID:0x618000180750 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000084ce0 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180750 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000845b0 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e1200(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.366 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000854b0 H:[NSImageView:0x618000163840(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6180000855f0 H:[NSImageView:0x618000163840]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6180001e1d00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085550 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x618000163840]   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180a90, '|':NameCellID:0x618000180a90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085500 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e1d00(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085640 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e1d00]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180a90, '|':NameCellID:0x618000180a90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000086ea0 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180a90 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085500 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e1d00(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.377 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000085f50 H:[NSImageView:0x610000162040(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000086090 H:[NSImageView:0x610000162040]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6100001e0d00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000085ff0 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x610000162040]   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000181e10, '|':NameCellID:0x610000181e10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000085fa0 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e0d00(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000860e0 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e0d00]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000181e10, '|':NameCellID:0x610000181e10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000086720 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000181e10 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000085fa0 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e0d00(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.390 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000087670 H:[NSImageView:0x600000162040(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000877b0 H:[NSImageView:0x600000162040]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6000001e1e00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000087710 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x600000162040]   (Names: NameCellID:0x600000181040, '|':NameCellID:0x600000181040 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000876c0 H:[NSTextField:0x6000001e1e00(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000087800 H:[NSTextField:0x6000001e1e00]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x600000181040, '|':NameCellID:0x600000181040 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000087df0 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x600000181040 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000876c0 H:[NSTextField:0x6000001e1e00(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.435 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000086ef0 H:[NSImageView:0x610000162880(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000851e0 H:[NSImageView:0x610000162880]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6100001e1800]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000086f90 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x610000162880]   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000182080, '|':NameCellID:0x610000182080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000086f40 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e1800(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000081040 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e1800]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000182080, '|':NameCellID:0x610000182080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000088160 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000182080 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000086f40 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e1800(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.458 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085cd0 H:[NSImageView:0x618000164740(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085e10 H:[NSImageView:0x618000164740]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6180001e2400]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085d70 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x618000164740]   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180b60, '|':NameCellID:0x618000180b60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085d20 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e2400(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085e60 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e2400]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180b60, '|':NameCellID:0x618000180b60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000086a40 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x618000180b60 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000085d20 H:[NSTextField:0x6180001e2400(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.470 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000087530 H:[NSImageView:0x610000162940(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000087670 H:[NSImageView:0x610000162940]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6100001e1d00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000875d0 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x610000162940]   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000182150, '|':NameCellID:0x610000182150 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000087580 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e1d00(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000876c0 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e1d00]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000182150, '|':NameCellID:0x610000182150 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000088160 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x610000182150 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000087580 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e1d00(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.481 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000088980 H:[NSImageView:0x6100001633c0(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000088ac0 H:[NSImageView:0x6100001633c0]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6100001e2800]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000088a20 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x6100001633c0]   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001823c0, '|':NameCellID:0x6100001823c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000889d0 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e2800(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000088b10 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e2800]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001823c0, '|':NameCellID:0x6100001823c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000089100 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(199)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001823c0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000889d0 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e2800(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2016-05-28 12:53:49.986 DSRenamer[42352:5539902] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000090810 H:[NSImageView:0x610000166b40(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000090b30 H:[NSImageView:0x610000166b40]-(7)-[NSTextField:0x6100001e4900]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000090a90 H:|-(3)-[NSImageView:0x610000166b40]   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001839b0, '|':NameCellID:0x6100001839b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000090950 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e4900(266)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000090b80 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e4900]-(-63)-|   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001839b0, '|':NameCellID:0x6100001839b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100000919e0 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[NameCellID(184)]   (Names: NameCellID:0x6100001839b0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000090950 H:[NSTextField:0x6100001e4900(266)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
May 28 12:54:39  DSRenamer[42352] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const: conn 0x2ed57: spurious update.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the constraints on textfields in the viewcontroller is creating some issues. Please have a look at the specific constraints regarding the textbox(es) with a value of 266 (probably the constraint regarding width). Try to delete it.

Comment: I found that contraint. I deleted it and all error were gone! Thank you very much.  P.S.: How did you know it was "266" and not one of the others?

Comment: Glad to hear! The app was automatically breaking the 266 constraint (see the warning, it is stated several times "Will attempt to recover by breaking ... (266)") indicating that deleting this constraint from the code would resolve the issues